# Connect to Azure SQL from Azure function using pypyodbc

Tags: python, azure-functions, odbc

I am trying to connect to an azure sql db from an azure function. I am using `pypyodbc`. I am not able to find the syntax for connecting to it. I have tried

```
import pypyodbc

def main(req):
    # Set up the database connection
    connection_string = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database_name>;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity;'
    connection = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

    # Execute a SQL query
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <table_name>')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Close the database connection
    connection.close()

    # Return the results
    return str(rows)
```

This gives the error

> (08001, '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid
> value specified for connection string attribute Authentication')
> Traceback (most recent call last):

What is the correct syntax, cannot find it.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16)? search for "active directory managed identity" in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code when using `pypyodbc` to connect from azure functions to azure sql db using managed idenitity

```
import pypyodbc

server = '<your_server_name>.database.windows.net'
database = '<your_database_name>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
auth = 'ActiveDirectoryMsi'

connection_string = (
    'DRIVER=' + driver + ';'
    'Server=' + server + ';'
    'Database=' + database + ';'
    'Authentication=' + auth + ';'
)

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

print("Connected")
```